# How to run hxnormalize on multiple files?

Tags: terminal, html

I have folder with multiple html files and I'd like to run hxnormalize on all of them and write the results back into the files.

I already tried `hxnormalize -e *.html` and `cat *.html | hxnormalize -e > *.html`

Comment: Please look up the `for` loop in your shell's man page. Do you know what shell you are using?

Comment: You may have clobbered one or more of your HTML files -- double-check the last one.

Comment: it's bash. how would a simple example for a loop that selects all html files look like? And what I still havn't figured out, how do I write the results back into the original files?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm sorry, I don't know what "clobbered" means, but the second command definitely doesn't work, I get "bash: *.html: ambiguous redirect" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/hxnormalize.1.html), hxnormalize work on a single file.

try

```
 for x in *.html
 do
    hxnormalize -e "$x" > foo
    mv -f foo "$x"
 done
```

you can remove quote if no funny name.

you can single line

```
for x in *.html ; do hxnormalize -e "$x" > foo ; mv -f foo "$x" ; done
```