# How to correctly remove a footer with hxremove?

Tags: terminal, html

I try to remove a footer section in multiple html files. For simplicity I started with just one file. The file contains:

```
<footer id="footer">
...
</footer>
```

I tried `hxremove footer foo.html`, but it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run hxnormalize on multiple files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394925/how-to-run-hxnormalize-on-multiple-files)

Comment: @peterh I don't think the question here as asked is a duplicate, because they're showing an issue when attempting to process a single file.

Comment: actually, I am the author of both questions and this one here is a follow up I ran into after the other question had been answered

Comment: @user430 Sorry - it seems I overlooked it. However, there is no more close vote from your question, thus it passed the review process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. These commands work from stdin to stdout. You have to use them like `hxremove selector <src.html >dst.html`.
2. My tests show they require at least a little bit valid html (`<html>`, `<body>` should be therein as usual).
3. Here you have to give a *valid (x)html selector*. `footer` is okay in this case, so it should work.

My example:

t.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a>cica</a>
    <p>cica</p>
    <p>cica</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the command `hxremove 'p' <t.html` outputs correctly

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a>cica</a>


  </body>
</html>
```

So, it can be made working, only you have to play a little bit more with it.

You can use the `hxnormalize` tool in the same software package to ensure, how things are looking in the eyes of the xhtml processor: the command `hxnormalize <t.html` outputs this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p><a>cica</a>

    <p>cica

    <p>cica
```

The seemingly unneeded empty lines are *correct behavior* - the selector remove only the html part, and not the text (this time, the whitespaces) between them.